# How to start C-STAT in IAR using command line in windows 7

Tags: command-line, static-analysis, iar

I'm trying to use C-STAT in IAR using only the command line (for Night build).

How can I do that? and how will i get the output (which format).

according to the user manual i'm typing the following command - and getting an error message

> " C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Em bedded Workbench
>   7.3_2\arm\cstat>icstat --db a.db --checks commands commands.txt
>
> 'icstat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. "

Is there a need to use "icstat" command in a specific path?
Is there a need to install an add-on, or any other program to enable command line commands?

Thanks

Comment: IAR products typically come with pretty good manuals. Did you read them? What have you tried so far? Why it didn't work?

Comment: I read the manual, but once trying to run "icstat" command or any other command written there - it only gives an error saying command is not recognized.

Comment: You are having specific problem with specific command, and specific error message. You should provide [mcve]. Be precise. Please [edit] your question, and add detail there, not in comments. My guess is that "icstat" is not in your PATH, but I cannot know for sure since question is missing so much information.

Comment: It seems that `icstat.exe` is not in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Em bedded Workbench 7.3_2\arm\cstat` folder. You should first find out where it is. It's probably in some subfolder of `Embedded Workbench 7.3_2` folder, but  I can't tell for sure as I don't have C-STAT.

Comment: Thanks, now i found it should be done at "C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.3_2\arm\bin "

Answer (score 0):

Now i found the path should be 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.3_2\arm\bin"